# I am applying float to only one element inside a container, yet the CSS applies to all the elements?

Tags: html, css

```css
.overflow-test {
  background-color: pink;
}

.float-test {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-test">

  <button class="float-test">News</button>
  <button>About</button>

</div>
```

I have only targeted the class inside the first button element, yet the CSS applies to both buttons. Why?

Comment: Actually to be more specific, the FLOAT rule applies to both. Color rules don't.

Comment: the float only apply to one button, what make you think it's applying to both?

Comment: An `id` must be unique in a page so with an `id` you'll target only 1 element. A class is not unique and may be used on many elements in a page. So if you use a class in the css, you will target all elements with that class. To be more specific, you may use something like `.overflow-test .float-test:first-child { ... }` But as said above, with your css  it will work only on the first burron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your About-button is not floated left like your News button. Instead, a button element seems to have a default CSS `display` value of `inline-block`. Any `inline` or `inline-block` elements will behave just like text within their containing element. Therefore, your About-button is placed at the right of the left-floating News-button. Just like text.

```css
.overflow-test {
  background-color: pink;
}

.float-test {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-test">

  <button class="float-test">News</button>
  Bla bla bla...
  <button>About</button>
  More bla bla bla...
</div>
```